# FindBugs warnings not displayed in Jenkins Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, findbugs, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Multibranch Pipeline job to trigger my build. One of the steps of the build is to run Sonar. After the Sonar is run, `findbugs-result.xml` file is created the `target/sonar` directory.

I publish the results using the below commands in Groovy. The build shows that there is 1 warning for FindBugs. But I do not see in the Jenkins Dashboard (FindBugs Warning portlet).

If I create a normal *Freestyle* job and try to do the same thing using a *Post-build action*, the results are visible on the Jenkins Dashboard.

```
bat "${env.M2_HOME}/bin/mvn sonar:sonar --settings ../HudsonSettings/settings.xml  -B -U -P reporting-plugins"

step([$class: 'FindBugsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canRunOnFailed: true, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', isRankActivated: true, pattern: '**/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml', unHealthy: ''])
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks and Regards

Saroj Gharat

Comment: I think there is an issue with multibranch pipelines and trend graphs not only for findbugs:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36536
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31202

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Jenkins-Findbugs will look for files with the name `findbugsXml.xml`.

If your integration is dropping a report with a report filename, you need to add the filename `findbugs-result.xml` (Under **Post-build action > Publish FindBugs analysis result > Findbugs results**).